# How to get latest timestamp data when join two tables

Tags: php, mysql, join

I have two tables (`plannertags` and `handovertable`) where I am trying to `JOIN` both.

`plannertags` contains unique entries identified by `srNumber` whereby `handovertable` contains a key (`plannerTagsId`) that link to `plannertags`'s `srNumber`. But `handovertable` can have multiple entries that has the same key of `plannertags`.

Here is my `handovertable`

[image]

Here you can see, there are two `plannerTagsId` that has the key (`plannerTagsId`) 17.

**What I need**

I need to `JOIN` and query data based on `handovertable`'s latest `handoverDate`. So what I expect after run query is to get only two entries from `handovertable` which has the `plannerTagsId` 16 and 17(that has the latest timestamp). I don't know how to get get latest `timestamp` and thus I tried `latestTag` as the selector. Query as below.

```
$tagQuery ="SELECT p.srNumber, h.handoverFrom, h.handoverRemarks FROM plannertags p
                                JOIN handovertable h
                                on p.srNumber = h.plannerTagsId
                               WHERE (p.status = '0' OR p.status = '2') AND p.currentStage = '1' AND p.assignedTo = '0' AND p.handoverStatus = '1' AND p.failedStatus = '1' AND h.latestTag = '1'
                               ORDER BY p.deliveryDate ASC";
```

Can someone guide how to tackle this problem using latest time stamp?

Comment: you need to add subquery with limit then use that into join...

Comment: I couldn't get it right with the suggested answer. The suggested answer is getting some MAX value. What I am requesting is how to get based on latest time stamp

Comment: @AntonyJack Can you give some sample?